# Gradle error while importing sample corda project

Tags: corda

I am trying to follow the documentation and sample code at [Github](https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/samples/notary-demo)

However as mentioned in documentation, I am not able to import the project in IntelliJ. I tried using Open project as well as import Gradle project, but it fails at each line. I tried modifying gradle file from sample code and added buildscript on top

```html
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    ext.junit_version = '4.12'
    ext.quasar_version = '0.7.9'
    ext.corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
    ext.corda_release_version = '3.1-corda'
    ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.1.0'
    ext.junit_version = '4.12'
    ext.quasar_version = '0.7.9'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordapp:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordformation:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:publish-utils:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases' }
}

//import net.corda.plugins.Cordform

apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.publish-utils'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

    // Corda integration dependencies
    cordaCompile project(":node")
    cordaCompile project(path: ":node:capsule", configuration: 'runtimeArtifacts')
    cordaCompile project(path: ":webserver:webcapsule", configuration: 'runtimeArtifacts')
    cordaCompile project(':core')
    cordaCompile project(':client:jfx')
    cordaCompile project(':client:rpc')
    cordaCompile project(':node-driver')
}

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true // defaults to false
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        jarAndSources(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifactId 'notarydemo'

            artifact sourceJar
            artifact javadocJar
        }
    }
}

task deployNodes(dependsOn: ['deployNodesSingle', 'deployNodesRaft', 'deployNodesBFT', 'deployNodesCustom'])

task deployNodesSingle(type: Cordform, dependsOn: 'jar') {
    definitionClass = 'net.corda.notarydemo.SingleNotaryCordform'
}

task deployNodesCustom(type: Cordform, dependsOn: 'jar') {
    definitionClass = 'net.corda.notarydemo.CustomNotaryCordform'
}

task deployNodesRaft(type: Cordform, dependsOn: 'jar') {
    definitionClass = 'net.corda.notarydemo.RaftNotaryCordform'
}

task deployNodesBFT(type: Cordform, dependsOn: 'jar') {
    definitionClass = 'net.corda.notarydemo.BFTNotaryCordform'
}

task notarise(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'net.corda.notarydemo.NotariseKt'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Automatic-Module-Name': 'net.corda.samples.demos.notary'
        )
    }
}
```

However, it still fails for applying plugin kotlin, import Cordform and compile project. Please guide on how to use these sample projects and run the same.

Thanks

Comment: Are you importing the sample folder directly? Try importing the entire Corda project instead.

Comment: Yes, it did work once I imported complete Corda. Can you recommend what structure to be followed when creating application from the scratch? I was earlier trying to import specific folder only to avoid additional project structure and keep project as basic as possible.

Comment: You should follow the example structure here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java.

Comment: Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of opening/importing the folder of the notary-demo sample directly, you need to import the entire Corda project instead.